# how can i add another UserManager and SignInManager in the different controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

when use mvc identity ,i have three database,and all of them have user table,in startup.cs there was a default UserManager and SignInManager,how can i add another UserManager and SignInManager in the different controller?(i mean i have different login page in the project, like accountAcontroller,accountBcontroller,this controllers have  different views to login)

```html
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContent;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ISmsSender smsSender,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            ApplicationDbContext Dbcontext
            )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _smsSender = smsSender;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
            _dbContent = Dbcontext;
        }
```